# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django==1.10.5 from versions: none ERROR: No matching distribution found Django==1.10.5

Tags: python, django

I am trying to install django with pip

```
pip insall django==1.10.5
```

I get the following error:

```
[1]WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/django/
C:\dev\django\entornos\srh\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:164: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning,
```

Comment: This tells very little. What are you trying to do? Install Django?

Comment: @pavel yes, i trying to install django with pip, pip insall django==1.10.5

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, try this command:

`shutdown /s`

If that doesn't work, try upgrading to the latest version of Python 2.7